# Изменить вывод имени файла (input file) через jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, файлы, input

у меня есть вот такой код:

```js
$(".input").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val().lastIndexOf('\\')) {
        var i = $(this).val().lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
    } else {
        var i = $(this).val().lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
    }
    var fileName = $(this).val().slice(i);
    $(".block").html(fileName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="input">
<div class="block"></div>
```

он выводит имя файла, а как можно сделать что бы было несколько input-ов  и для каждого выводилось свое имя :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".input").change(function() {
        var $el = $(this),
            fileName,
            $block = $el.next('.block');
    if ($el.val().lastIndexOf('\\')) {
        var i = $el.val().lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
    } else {
        var i = $el.val().lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
    }
    fileName = $el.val().slice(i);
    $block.html(fileName);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sptyuLvw/4/

Comment: Да я проверил код, помогло спасибо большое ))

Answer (score 1):

К примеру, можно использовать `data-*` атрибуты. Каждому `input` задать уникальный `id` (*например data-id="1"*). Также в блоке, куда выводим имя файла задать `class` с учётом этого `id`, ну и выводить уже в `div` с нужным нам `class`

```js
$(".input").change(function (){
    if ($(this).val().lastIndexOf('\\')){
        var i = $(this).val().lastIndexOf('\\')+1;
    }
    else{
        var i = $(this).val().lastIndexOf('/')+1;
    }
    var fileName = $(this).val().slice(i);
    $(".block_"+$(this).data("id")).html(fileName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="input" data-id="1">
<div class="block_1"></div><br/>
<hr/>
<input type="file" class="input" data-id="2">
<div class="block_2"></div>
```

Comment: Ваш код тоже очень помог, спасибо большое ))